# readinessProbe does not seem to wait for initial delay

Tags: kubernetes

### Overview

This is my first time setting up a readinessProbe, so I may be missing something very basic.

I have a deployment with two pods. One runs nginx and the other builds an application and drops the assets into a build directory, which is a volume that both containers share. The container that builds the assets takes a minute or two to complete. Here is my deployment.yaml (abridged):

```
 ...
  containers:
  - name: personal-site-container
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - ls
        - /opt/dist/js/app.*.js
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
    image: <username>/<image>:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - name: build-volume
      mountPath: /opt/dist
  - name: nginx-server
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - ls
        - /usr/share/nginx/html/js/app.*.js
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
    image: nginx:1.19.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: build-volume
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
```

### What I expect to happen

Because the `ls` command will succeed when the assets have been built, but fail when an asset with that name does not exist, I expect that the probe will run after two minutes and then set the status of both containers to READY.

### What actually happens

When I apply this deployment, everything goes as expected (logs in personal-site-container show that the static assets are building and 0/2 containers are in READY state) for the first *almost* 1 minute, and then the pod enters a crash backoff loop. When I view the events with:

```
k get event --field-selector involvedObject.name=personal-site-5b595d46db-tmsrb
```

I see a "Back-off restarting failed container" event, which is of type "warning", but no errors of any kind.

### Question(s)

What else might I do to investigate why the readinessProbe does not seem to be waiting for 120 seconds before changing the readiness status? If the solution is obvious, what am I missing here?

Comment: What does your container do after he perform the file generation? Does it sleep or exists? Do you know which container is crashing? Do you have any pod logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Back-off restarting failed container" has nothing to do with the readiness probe. Failing readiness probe never causes a container to be killed or restarted. It is just responsible for considering the container ready for serving requests and for adding it to the load balancer of a service.

> the other builds an application and drops the assets into a build directory

What I suspect here is that the personal-site-container builds the assets and exits. As the default restart policy is `always`, the container gets restarted, and so on, and so on, it enters a "back-off restart" loop.

By the way, readiness probe for the personal-site-container makes not much sense. First, it does not belong to any service, second it's meant to do the job and exit (as far as I understand). You might want to have a look on Kubernetes [jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

Comment: That was it, thanks! I actually ended up just rewriting the image so that the assets are built when the image is built.

Comment: I was curious to see if I could do the build after deployment but it ended up being a headache.